specify ggsankey color fill from center to left and right
I am building a Sankey diagram using ggsankey in R with 3 columns (org_group, main_mech, and energy_group) I want to make it so all flows from the middle column (energy group) that connect to ambient energy are red with all the others remaining grey. I have only been able to do it from left to right and have not seen a way to change the fill color of the flow based on the right node. Heres my code and first diagram attempt based on the RPubs article I found:
    library(ggsankey)
    TotalCount=nrow(data)



     enrg<- data %>% make_long(org_group,energy_group,main_mech)

     dagg <- enrg%>%
       dplyr::group_by(node)%>%
       tally()

    dagg <- dagg%>%
      dplyr::group_by(node)%>%
      dplyr::mutate(pct = n/TotalCount)


    # Step 3
    df2 <- merge(enrg, dagg, by.x = 'node', by.y = 'node', all.x = TRUE)

    pl <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x
                      , next_x = next_x
                      , node = node
                      , next_node = next_node
                      , fill = factor(node)
                      
                      , label = paste0(node ))
)
 
    pl <- pl +geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5,  color = "gray40", show.legend = TRUE)
     pl <- pl +geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "black", fill= "white", hjust   =    -0.1)

    pl <- pl +  theme_bw()
    pl <- pl + theme(legend.position = "none")
    pl <- pl +  theme(axis.title = element_blank()
                  , axis.text.y = element_blank()
                  , axis.ticks = element_blank()  
                  , panel.grid = element_blank())
    pl <- pl + scale_fill_manual(values =c('ambient energy'= "red"))


    pl

heres my attempt so far
So far, Ive only seen how to change the nodes and flows based on the left node
